# Can i use AND operator 2 times in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

So i been trying this for a week, which is the value inside the table is missing after i select submit button for the date

So when enter the this page it will display

```
'SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE lect_id = 'CS0198289' AND dateofupdate LIKE '%0%' AND codeofsubject = 'CSNB214' ORDER BY studname ASC'
```

which is it will display my lect_id, dateofupdate=0, and the code of subject. When I select the submit(SELECT) button which is to date it will become

```
'SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE lect_id = 'CS0198289' AND dateofupdate LIKE '%2019-01-23%' AND codeofsubject = '' ORDER BY studname ASC'
```

so can anyone help me? much appreciate

```
<?php
                $connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","ubas")
                or die("Cannot connect to server".mysqli_error($connect));

                if (!isset($_POST['dates'])){
                  $_POST['dates']=0;
                }
                $id = @$_POST["lect_id"];
                $codeofsubject = @$_POST['code'];

                $display = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE lect_id = '$_SESSION[id]' AND dateofupdate LIKE '%".$_POST['dates']."%'
                AND codeofsubject = '$codeofsubject' ORDER BY studname ASC";
                echo $display;
                $result = mysqli_query ($connect,$display)
                or die ("Cannot view due to".mysqi_error($connect));

                echo"<form role='form' method='post'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                          <label>Date</label>
                          <input style='width:180px; display:inline' class='form-control' type='date' name='dates' id='dates'>
                          <button type='submit' style='display:inline' name='select'>Select</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>";

                echo"
                <form method = post action = updateattend.php>
                <table width='100%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th><center>Date</center></th>
                              <th><center>Student Name</center></th>
                              <th><center>Student ID</center></th>
                              <th><center>View</center></th>
                              <th><center>Attend Status</center></th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>";
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
                      {
                        $attendid = $row [0];
                        $studname = $row [1];
                        $studid = $row [2];
                        $lect_id = $row [3];
                        $codeofsubject = $row [4];
                        $date = $row [5];
                        $dateofenroll = $row [6];
                        $attendstatus = $row [7];

                          echo"<tbody>
                          <tr>
                          <td><center>$date</center></td>
                          <td><center>$studname</center></td>
                          <td><center>$studid</center></td>
                          <td align = center>
                          <a class ='btn-warning btn' href ='updatestud.php?id=".$row['2']."'>VIEW</a>
                          </td>";
                          echo"

                          <td align = center>
                          <select class = 'form-control' name = 'attendstatus[]'>
                          <option value='$attendstatus' selected>$attendstatus</option>";

                          if($attendstatus =="Attend")
                          {
                            echo "<option value='Not Attending'>Not Attending</option>
                            <option value='Not Attending with Reason'>Not Attending with Reason</option>";
                          }
                          elseif ($attendstatus =="Not Attending") {
                            echo"<option value='Attend'>Attend</option>
                            <option value='Not Attending with Reason'>Not Attending with Reason</option>";
                          }
                          else{
                            echo"<option value='Attend'>Attend</option>
                            <option value='Not Attending'>Not Attending</option>";
                          }

                          echo"</select>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>";
                      }

                      ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: Obligatory SQL injection comment here.

Comment: Yes you can as you did. More questions?

Comment: Why it doesn't not show any value at codeofsubject when i click submit button ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit of `AND` operator in `SQL` statement. You can use as many `AND`s as you need but your logic should be correct in the sense of `SQL` statement.

**For Example**

```
SELECT something FROM something WHERE something=something AND something=something AND something=something AND something=something;
```

So, the part `something=something` becomes a separate logical statement that is separately evaluated from other `something=something` statements based on the `AND` operator. But keep in mind that the whole statement above is a single statement.

Comment: But why does it not show any value at codeofsubject after i click the select button ? there is no error and the output will become like this when i echo $display; on my page 'SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE lect_id = 'CS0198289' AND dateofupdate LIKE '%2019-01-23%' AND codeofsubject = '' ORDER BY studname ASC'